# Import "pygame" could not be resolved

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I installed pygame using the pip in command prompt but it still shows an error. I have already attempted changing the path so pip could properly be accessed and using the line "pygame.init()" but the error still appears.

Here's the code:

---

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

w, h = 600, 600
r = (255, 0, 0)

s = pygame.display.set_mode( (w, h) )
s.fill(r)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Comment: DId you install `pygame` by running `pip install pygame`? If so, then it is possible that the python installation tied to your `pip` is different from the one you are using to import the package. Installing with `python -m pip install pygame` *might* solve it, *iff* the copy of python in your path is the same one you are using to import the package.

Comment: Please edit your post to write your code. :)

Comment: Thank you Esraa, this is my first question so I didnt think to do that :p

also when I tried python -m pip install pygame it returned "Python was not found"

Comment: Which OS are you on? Try using `pip3 install pygame` or `python3 -m pip install pygame`

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and I tried both of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the way if it still isn't working you could try using Pycharm. If you can't do that you could try using replit and downloading the pygame package, then exporting it with Github.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).